# datatable responsiveness wont adapt to page resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, datatable

I have a jsfiddle example with a couple different card - boxes, I am trying to work on the responsiveness for my 'Table 1' box but am running into an issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/0hmq8skj/14/

```
code
```

If you got to the jsfiddle and have a large enough browser window, you can see the page initially load like this:
[image]

I'm happy with the location of all these boxes. Now if you resize the window to be smaller with, say, chrome's inspect element console tool, the page will resize and move the 'Table 1' box like so:

[image]

I'm fine with this resizing too. The issue is, if I want to go back to the resizing in my first image, I need to refresh the page. If i simply remove the chrome console dev tool so the page returns to the dimensions from image 1, the table 1 box does not go back to normal:
[image]

How can i prevent this? Is there some extra class or bootstrap styling or css I need to include in my Table 1 box so that it will resize correctly? This is really bugging me.

THanks, Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .col to  .col-lg-6 to both the divs under " left column (mycomplandscape/barGraph)" and " right column (table)". You could also change both to .col-md-6 if you want a smaller breakpoint to a single stack.Should look like:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column">
```

Updated the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ykLtu8dx/